# Forward slash become %2F

Tags: c#

I have this endpoint which has one string parameter. When I tested the `name` payload with "a / b", it becomes "a %2F b". I put a breakpoint at the action method to see it. How do I prevent `/` to become `%2F`? What I expected is the value will be still the same "a / b". This is because there is a slash symbol in someone's name. If possible, I don't want to use the replace method.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateName(int id, string name)
    {
        // code is removed for brevity
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like UrlDecode ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urldecode?view=net-6.0#system-web-httputility-urldecode(system-string)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really prevented because `/` is used to divide parts of the address, however you can decode it.

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("a %2F b"));
```

prints

```
a / b
```

Please note that this happens not only to `/`. Here' an example for &

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("a & b")
//a+%26+b
```